# Insert text in the middle of variable, after "X" text

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, registry

First of all, English is not my mother tongue so sorry if I don't express myself correctly. I'm trying to create a batch file to fix a known issue with one software that we have. The thing is that we have too many machines to do it manually and so I was trying to create the batch for that. What we need to do is the following:

1) Look for a registry value:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder

2) Open the "List" value and add a text string after "Event Log"

That's it.

A little disclaimer: This has to run in every possible scenario, so I can't depend on the machine having X software (.net framework 4.5 for example). Also, cant download third party software, I have to limit myself to what's included in the OS (Windows 7 and up)

This is the initial code that I have until now:

```
REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder /v List | FIND /i "List" > Clave_Registro.txt
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("Clave_Registro.txt") DO SET _REGISTRO=%%G
SET _REGISTRO=%_REGISTRO:    =!%
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=!" %%G IN ("%_REGISTRO%") DO (
    SET _REGISTRO=%%G
    )
```

With this, I got the list from the registry (_REGISTRO), looks something like this:

> System Reserved\0EMS\0WdfLoadGroup\0Boot Bus Extender\0System Bus
>   Extender\0SCSI miniport\0Port\0Primary Disk\0SCSI Class\0SCSI CDROM
>   Class\0FSFilter Infrastructure\0FSFilter System\0FSFilter
>   Bottom\0FSFilter Copy Protection\0FSFilter Security Enhancer\0FSFilter
>   Open File\0FSFilter Physical Quota Management\0FSFilter
>   Virtualization\0FSFilter Encryption\0FSFilter Compression\0FSFilter
>   Imaging\0FSFilter HSM\0FSFilter Cluster File System\0FSFilter System
>   Recovery\0FSFilter Quota Management\0FSFilter Content
>   Screener\0FSFilter Continuous Backup\0FSFilter Replication\0FSFilter
>   Anti-Virus\0FSFilter Undelete\0FSFilter Activity Monitor\0FSFilter
>   Top\0Filter\0Boot File System\0Base\0Pointer Port\0Keyboard
>   Port\0Pointer Class\0Keyboard Class\0Video Init\0Video\0Video
>   Save\0File System\0Streams Drivers\0NDIS Wrapper\0COM
>   Infrastructure\0Event Log\0ProfSvc_Group\0AudioGroup\0UIGroup\0MS_WindowsLocalValidation\0PlugPlay\0Cryptography\0PNP_TDI\0NDIS\0TDI\0iSCSI\0NetBIOSGroup\0ShellSvcGroup\0SchedulerGroup\0SpoolerGroup\0SmartCardGroup\0NetworkProvider\0MS_WindowsRemoteValidation\0NetDDEGroup\0Parallel
>   arbitrator\0Extended Base\0PCI Configuration\0MS Transactions

The thing is that now I have to insert something after "Event Log" and then insert it back to the registry.

It would be something like this:

> System Reserved\0EMS\0WdfLoadGroup\0Boot Bus Extender\0System Bus
>   Extender\0SCSI miniport\0Port\0Primary Disk\0SCSI Class\0SCSI CDROM
>   Class\0FSFilter Infrastructure\0FSFilter System\0FSFilter
>   Bottom\0FSFilter Copy Protection\0FSFilter Security Enhancer\0FSFilter
>   Open File\0FSFilter Physical Quota Management\0FSFilter
>   Virtualization\0FSFilter Encryption\0FSFilter Compression\0FSFilter
>   Imaging\0FSFilter HSM\0FSFilter Cluster File System\0FSFilter System
>   Recovery\0FSFilter Quota Management\0FSFilter Content
>   Screener\0FSFilter Continuous Backup\0FSFilter Replication\0FSFilter
>   Anti-Virus\0FSFilter Undelete\0FSFilter Activity Monitor\0FSFilter
>   Top\0Filter\0Boot File System\0Base\0Pointer Port\0Keyboard
>   Port\0Pointer Class\0Keyboard Class\0Video Init\0Video\0Video
>   Save\0File System\0Streams Drivers\0NDIS Wrapper\0COM
>   Infrastructure\0Event Log\0**TEXT TO BE INSERTED**\0ProfSvc_Group\0AudioGroup\0UIGroup\0MS_WindowsLocalValidation\0PlugPlay\0Cryptography\0PNP_TDI\0NDIS\0TDI\0iSCSI\0NetBIOSGroup\0ShellSvcGroup\0SchedulerGroup\0SpoolerGroup\0SmartCardGroup\0NetworkProvider\0MS_WindowsRemoteValidation\0NetDDEGroup\0Parallel
>   arbitrator\0Extended Base\0PCI Configuration\0MS Transactions

Do you guys know any way to add the text string in the middle just after "Event log"?

Thanks!

Comment: `SET _REGISTRO=%_REGISTRO:0Event Log\=0Event Log\0TEXT TO BE INSERTED\%`

Comment: Then read the help for how to add to the registry by opening a cmd prompt and typing: `reg add /?`

Comment: OMG, i feel so ashamed that it was that easy, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!